# How to represent normalized data in a single CSV

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I have normalized database tables, lets call them `users`, `emails` and `addresses`.  I want to output all of this data in a single CSV file, but without excessive duplication that a standard `LEFT JOIN` would give.

For example, given this data:

```
Users:
id  |  name
----------------
1   |  Alice
2   |  Bill
3   |  Charlie


Emails:
user_id  |  email
------------------------------
1        |  alice@home.com
1        |  alice@work.com
1        |  alice@work2.net
3        |  charlie@home.com
3        |  charlie@work.net


Addresses
user_id  |  street_address      |  city        | state  | zip
----------------------------------------------------------------
1        |  111 Home St         | Homeville    | AB     | 11111
1        |  222 Work St         | Workville    | CD     | 20000
1        |  223 Work St         | Workville    | CD     | 20000
2        |  333 Bill Ave        | Workville    | CD     | 20000
3        |  444 Nice Rd         | Shady Hill   | EF     | 30000
```

a standard LEFT JOIN would give a total of 9 rows for Alice (3 emails * 3 addresses), but all her unique data could be represented in just three lines.

The output I would like to achieve is:

```
user_id  |  name    | email            |  street_address     |  city        | state  | zip
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |  Alice   | alice@home.com   | 111 Home St         | Homeville    | AB    | 11111
1        |          | alice@work.com   | 222 Work St         | Workville    | CD    | 20000
1        |          | alice@work2.net  | 223 Work St         | Workville    | CD    | 20000
2        |  Bill    |                  | 333 Bill Ave        | Workville    | CD    | 20000
3        |  Charlie | charlie@home.com | 444 Nice Rd         | Shady Hill   | EF    | 30000
3        |          | charlie@work.net |                     |              |       |
```

Is there a name for this kind of data format?  Do pandas or Postgres (or other tools / langs) have functionality to create this kind of combined data format?

Comment: Yes it is called JSON.

Comment: I agree that JSON would be a better interchange data format, but this is for human consumption, most likely through Excel.

Comment: I don't know of any prebuilt option.